# Strange behaviour w/ bootstrap 3 layout in Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, mozilla

I'm having an issue with the layout of `col-lg-3` elements in the latest version of Firefox.
You can see the issue here: http://dev2014.rab.co.uk/case-studies/
Oddly enough, I have tested this in an older version of Firefox and the issue doesn't seem to exist.

I'm wondering if it has to do with the `moz-box-sizing` element.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with Bootstrap/Firefox?
I've tested on webkit browsers and it's not an issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is this Text 'H&M – Fashion Against Aids', while every other Box has only one Line at this point, this Box has a doubleline there and i think it is just rendered 1px biggen than in the older version.

The result is that this box is 1px bigger and according to that the next box is not starting from the left side, but in fact from under the second box column.

You need to change this

```
.case-thumb {
    min-height:300px;
}
```

to this

```
.case-thumb {
    min-height:345px;
}
```